# Syntax error at or near $1 while trying to alter type in postgreSQL-9.6

Tags: c#, npgsql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to add a value to an enumerated type in postgreSQL-9.6, and am having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

```
var tc = new NpgsqlCommand(@"ALTER TYPE attributeName ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 
:a", conn);

//tc.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("a", NpgsqlDbType.Text));
//tc.Parameters[0].Value = "test";
tc.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", NpgsqlDbType.Text, "test");

tc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried both the commented out code and the current version, and both resulted in an exception. The exception details are:

```
$exception  {"42601: syntax error at or near \"$1\""}
```

I understand the $1 is in reference to the text being passed through the "a" parameter, but I don't understand why there is a problem or how to fix it. PostgreSQL's documentation says that ALTER TYPE cannot be performed in a transaction block, but as far as I can tell Npgsql doesn't automatically start transactions, so that shouldn't be a problem. If I perform a different SQL command with similar syntax, such as:

```
var tc = new NpgsqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO test VALUES (:a)", conn);
```

the program works flawlessly. Also, if I type the command directly into the psql shell, like this:

```
ALTER TYPE attributeName ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 'test';
```

it works as expected. Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This does not appear to be your actual code, unless you really do have an attribute called `attributeName`.

Comment: I actually do, it's in reference to an attribute on an item in a game, so it made sense to me to name it that. I'm not sure if you're suggesting it's a keyword and will cause problems because of that or it's just bad practice to name it that though. I will try to think of a better name. Maybe modName or traitName?

Comment: No, no, it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think it can't be achieved for the same reason a table name cannot be passed as a query parameter.

However, you can use a string replacement for it:

```
string name = "test";
var tc = new NpgsqlCommand($"ALTER TYPE attributeName ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS '{name}'", conn);
```

Please keep in mind it's not a secure approach!

**UPDATE:**

Another solution would be usage of a stored procedure that executes the command. However, you cannot simply call the `ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE ...` command inside a procedure/function because it doesn't work inside transaction blocks. You would get the following error:

> "ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot be executed from a function or
>   multi-command string"

This thread should shed some light on the issue: [Problems with ENUM type manipulation in 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/29F36C7C98AB09499B1A209D48EAA615B7653DBC8A%40mail2a.alliedtesting.com)

However, there might be a solution for your problem. It looks like you're trying to modify the existing enum type (add a new value). You can create a function that operates on the `pg_enum` table directly. The set of database functions, designed for enum types manipulation, can found here: [PostgreSQL 8.3+, 9.1+ ALTER ENUM emulation: element addition/removal, transactions](http://en.dklab.ru/lib/dklab_postgresql_enum/).

The function that adds a new value to existing enum looks as follows:

```
-- Also works within transactions in PostgreSQL 9.1+ (but you need
-- to reconnect to the database after transaction commit, because 
-- new enum items are not be visible within the session you used
-- to add them).
--
-- See http://en.dklab.ru/lib/dklab_postgresql_enum/
--
-- (C) Dmitry Koterov, 2013
-- This code is BSD licensed.
--

CREATE SCHEMA enum AUTHORIZATION postgres;


SET search_path = enum, pg_catalog;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enum.enum_add (
  enum_name varchar,
  enum_elem varchar
)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
DECLARE
    eoid OID;
    has_sortorder BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    eoid := (
        SELECT pg_type.oid
        FROM pg_type JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_type.typnamespace
        WHERE typtype='e' AND enum_name IN(typname, nspname||'.'||typname)
    );
    has_sortorder := EXISTS(
        select 1
        from pg_attribute
        where attrelid=(select oid from pg_class where relname='pg_enum') and attname='enumsortorder'
    );
    IF has_sortorder THEN
        EXECUTE '
            INSERT INTO pg_enum(enumtypid, enumlabel, enumsortorder) VALUES(
                '||eoid||',
                '||quote_literal(enum_elem)||',
                (SELECT MAX(enumsortorder) + 1 FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid='||eoid||')
            )
        ';
    ELSE
        EXECUTE E'INSERT INTO pg_enum(enumtypid, enumlabel) VALUES('||eoid||', '||quote_literal(enum_elem)||')';
    END IF;
END;
$body$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

COMMENT ON FUNCTION enum.enum_add (enum_name character varying, enum_elem character varying) IS 'Inserts a new ENUM element wthout re-creating the whole type.';
```

Now, you can just call the stored procedure/function from your C# code:

```
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"enum.enum_add";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("enum_name", "attributeName");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("enum_elem", "O'Reilly");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Please note, that the above function will fail if you try to add an existing value.

Comment: I tried this, but the strings I'm entering have characters that need to be escaped like `'` in them, and I'm not entirely sure how to handle that. I was hoping solving the root issue would be simpler than doing a string replacement. To be clear, this does work for strings without characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: It seems like string replacing is my best option. To solve my problem with escaping single quotes I am using `inputString.Replace(@"'", @"''")`. I am getting data from an API and not from users in this case so I don't have to worry as much about SQL injection, but other users may want to use a more robust method of escaping characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with npgsql, though might be totally wrong, but NpgsqlCommand [seems to execute prepared statement](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html). If so, [you cant prepare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) ALTER statement:

> **statement**
>
> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement.

Comment: I think you actually have to use `command.Prepare();` to have a command be prepared, so while you may not be able to prepare an `ALTER` statement, I don't think this is the problem. By default, as far as I can tell, Npgsql uses unprepared commands. This is further supported by the fact that entering the command through string replacement as suggested by mieczyk does actually work.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't support parameter placeholders everywhere, and unless I'm mistaken it's specifically unsupported in DDL statements such as `ALTER TYPE`. You will likely have to insert the value you want as a literal in your statement (be sure to take into account SQL injection).

Comment: I only have to deal with single quotes in my strings because they are not user supplied. Is there a better way to handle escaping single quotes than `inputString.Replace(@"'", @"''")`?